# Printing on separate lines from a list

Tags: prolog

Suppose I have a list

```
display(['1.Stack','2.Over','3.Flow','4.dotcom']).
```

When I put a query like `display(X)` it prints all in a single line.I want it to be displayed on separate lines.
I can do it by recursion and printing the head of the list everytime,but is there some other way to do this??because I want to make my code shorter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by applying `writeln` to list elements using `maplist/2`:

```
mylist([quick,brown,fox,jumps,over,the,lazy,dog]).

:-mylist(X), maplist(writeln, X).
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/DUKXp4).

The above prints

```
quick
brown
fox
jumps
over
the
lazy
dog
```